# How do I optimize point-to-circle matching?

Tags: postgresql, computational-geometry

I have a table that contains a bunch of Earth coordinates (latitude/longitude) and associated radii. I also have a table containing a bunch of points that I want to match with those circles, and vice versa. Both are dynamic; that is, a new circle or a new point can be added or deleted at any time. When either is added, I want to be able to match the new circle or point with all applicable points or circles, respectively.

I currently have a PostgreSQL module containing a C function to find the distance between two points on earth given their coordinates, and it seems to work. The problem is scalability. In order for it to do its thing, the function currently has to scan the whole table and do some trigonometric calculations against each row. Both tables are indexed by latitude and longitude, but the function can't use them. It has to do its thing before we know whether the two things match. New information may be posted as often as several times a second, and checking every point every time is starting to become quite unwieldy.

I've looked at PostgreSQL's geometric types, but they seem more suited to rectangular coordinates than to points on a sphere.

How can I arrange/optimize/filter/precalculate this data to make the matching faster and lighten the load?

Comment: Are your radii small enough to treat the local area as flat?  Do you have any constraints on the potential inputs for the points (say, all in Australia or something)?

Comment: @MarkPing: The radii can be as big as 500 miles, maybe more.  The points are all in the US and Canada, and perhaps Mexico.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't mentioned [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/) - why have you ruled that out as a possibility?

http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/PostGIS_Special_Functions_Index.html#PostGIS_GeographyFunctions

Comment: I haven't ruled much of anything out.  Just didn't see any mention of that stuff in the docs  :P  I'm open to pretty much anything that'll work better than what i have.

Comment: If you haven't come across PostGIS then stop what you are doing and read around the subject of Geographical Information Systems. Otherwise you'll waste all your time recreating solutions that have already got reliable, efficient and tested implementations

Answer (score 2):

Thinking out loud a bit here...  you have a point (lat/long) and a radius, and you want to find all extisting point-radii combinations that may overlap? (or some thing like that...)

Seems you might be able to store a few more bits of information Along with those numbers that could help you rule out others that are nowhere close during your query... This might avoid a lot of trig operations.

Example, with point x,y and radius r, you could easily calculate a range a feasible lat/long (squarish area) that could be used to help rule it out if needless calculations against another point.

You could then store the max and min lat and long along with that point in the database. Then, before running your trig on every row, you could Filter your results to eliminate points obviously out of bounds.

Comment: Looks like @Opi had similar idea while I was typing mine!

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand you correctly then my first idea would be to cache some data and eliminate most of the checking.

Like imagine your circle is actually a box and it has 4 sides

you could store the base coordinates of those lines much like you have lines (a mesh) on a real map. So you store east, west, north, south edge of each circle

If you get your coordinate and its outside of that box you can be sure it won't be inside the circle either since the box is bigger than the circle.

If it isn't then you have to check like you do now. But I guess you can eliminate most of the steps already.

Comment: Lat/long coordinates are kinda a pain in that a "box" with them doesn't actually form a rectangle.  It deforms more and more, and gets smaller and smaller, as you get further away from the equator.  You know of a reliable way to test against such a box?

Comment: You'll need to use some form of map projecting algoritm for this then. Basically you need to calculate how this box would look like on a flat surface to use Euclidean geometry. You might need to calculate things according to some kind of non-euclidean geometry as a start then transform those values. But yeah this actually sounds like an intersting problem